# Use QlineEdit to update SQLite database in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to get multiple QLineEdit objects to update on clicking a submit pushbutton to the SQLite db. I also have a QTableView that displays the db. The submit button adds a row to the database but does not save it. I would like the line edits to be added to the newly created row.

```
import sys
from testdbtableform import *
from PyQt4 import *
from PyQt4 import QtSql, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtSql import (QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlRelation,
        QSqlRelationalDelegate, QSqlRelationalTableModel)


def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('demomap.db')
    db.open()
    print (db.lastError().text())
    return True

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("userlist")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.Submit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.dbinput)

    def dbinput(self):
        row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(row)
        self.model.submitAll()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have 2 line edits to input to columns of username and email. If I could get an example of how to use it correctly I would be able to understand the rest of the inputs. I am fairly new to python and pyqt. If I must switch it to pyside I am willing to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
from testdbtableform import *
from PyQt4 import QtSql, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('demomap.db')
    if db.open():
        return True
    else:
        print db.lastError().text()
        return False

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable("userlist")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(2)
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.Submit.clicked.connect(self.dbinput)

    def dbinput(self):
        self.model.insertRow(-1)
        text = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
        if self.model.setData(self.model.index(-1, 0), text):
            self.model.submitAll()
        else:
            print "There was a problem setting the data."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I changed dbinput to show you how it should work and I also cleaned up a few other bits of your code that needed help.

This should work for the most part but I can't test it without you db file and your ui file.

It looks like you need to spend a little more time reading and understanding the documentation. http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html

Good luck with it.

Comment: Thank you for the help but unfortunately it didn't work. I agree I need to read more on it to understand it better, and that is what I am trying to do. Also the way the documentation is does confuse me a bit but I'm sure I'll get better at it.

Comment: If you want to send me your db file and your ui file I can look at it a little more for you. You can email it to me on the pyqt mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You should commit data to the database. Using OnManualSubmit caches the data into the model.

`self.model.submitAll()` maybe?

Comment: Right I now have that added but the line edit will not submit to the database. It submits a blank row.

Comment: If you get a blank row, one suspects that you are getting blank (null) data from the lineedit. Add a print to display the text value to the console before the setdata, or step through with an IDE and verify that there is something there.